# In Wordpress, how to use get_template_part_{slug} to change the args for get_template_part?

Tags: wordpress, templates, variables, hook

I'm trying to keep logic out of my templates. I want to pass a variable into a template part so in single.php I have:

`get_template_part('template-parts/the-slug', null, ['example' => 1]);`

In functions.php I have this function and have added it to get_template_part_template-parts/the-slug something like:

```
add_action('populate', 'get_template_part_template-parts/the-slug');

public function populate( $name, $template, $args ){
   print_r($args);
   $args['another var'] = 2; 
}
```

So the function fires fine. My issue is that I want to set the $args (or some other variable) in populate() to make them usable within the template part. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **get_template_part()** does not natively support passing variables to the included template file. The third parameter you're passing to get_template_part() in your single.php file doesn't actually do anything in WordPress's default implementation of get_template_part().

Second, **add_action()** is not used to extend the functionality of a function like **get_template_part()**. Instead, add_action() is used to link a function to a specific action that is triggered within WordPress. The action 'populate' is not a default WordPress action, and is not related to get_template_part().

You can use **set_query_var()** to make a variable available to the template part.